Command line to open outlook's "To do" app
Outlook offers a new "To do" app. I would like to make a shortcut to access the Tasks menu on this app, as shown in the picture.
Both of these commands open the old version, the "Tasks" app, which is not what I want:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle /select outlook:To-do%20list
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle /select outlook:tasks


Did you try with space instead of %20?

@Destroy666 I tried "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle /select "outlook:To-do list" and it opens the old version. Omitting the "list" or hyphen is invalid.

Do you want to open a new version of Outlook with commands?

@Soki No, which is why the recycle switch is there

Do you mean the "Microsoft To Do" app which opens in a new window? It's "ToDo.exe" located in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Todos_2.114.7122.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe . The exact location might differ between installations. You can pin it to the taskbar.

@1NN  no. not that. See the screenshot in the question. It is an embedded app within Outlook. But, using a separate app like that (I'm sure it's linked to what shows in Outlook) could be useful as well. Thanks for the idea.

To open Outlook’s “To Do” app from the command line, you can use the following command:
outlook.exe /select "outlook:tasks"


As shown in the original question, I've used this, but it opens the old tasks app, which is what I'm trying to avoid.
